# Что случилось со сниппетами?

Tags: дефект, сниппеты

Все сниппеты на сайте выдают

> #### Service Unavailable
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Кстати, [как известно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454670/178988), сниппеты можно сделать вообще без серверного кода.

[image: ask]

[image: run]

[image: answer]

Comment: Скриншоты в студию.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил 3 скриншота - задать вопрос, запустить любой существующий сниппет, добавить сниппет в ответ. И мне очень интересно, чем эти скриншоты помогли.

Comment: оказывается, я этим никогда не пользовался.

Comment: [how-can-i-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285740/how-can-i-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Nicolas уже [отписался о проблеме](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33251904#33251904)

Comment: сниппеты заработали

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-не-воспроизводится]

Comment: Да, заработали.